# Scraping a website using PHP "Simple HTML Dom Parser"

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for pulling information from a website.

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://example.com');

$ret = array();
foreach($html->find(".project-card-mini-wrap") as $element)  { 
   echo $element;   
}
```

The output of `$element` is:

```
<div class="project-card-mini-wrap"> 
<a class="project_item block mb2 green-dark"    href="/projects/andrewkostirev/kostirev-the-real-you">
<div class="project_thumbnail hover-group border border-box mb1"> 
     <img alt="Project image" class="hover-zoomin fit" src="https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/projects/2123706/photo-original.png?v=1444253259&amp;w=218&amp;h=162&amp;fit=crop&amp;auto=format&amp;q=92&amp;s=9d6c437e96b720dce82fc9b598b3e8ae" /> 
    <div class="funding_tag highlight">10 days to go</div> 
   <div class="hover-zoomout bg-green-90"> 
   <p class="white p2 h5">A clothing brand like never seen before</p> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="project_name h5 bold"> KOSTIREV - THE REAL YOU </div>
</a>
</div>
```

This is the information I'd like to pull from the website:
1: Link href
2: Image src
3: Project name

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: upload, or download?

Comment: i have tried every thing as in First answer

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will provide some insight to you as well as other users of **[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)**

```
foreach($html->find(".project-card-mini-wrap") as $element)  { 
   echo "Project name: ",$element->find('.project_name',0)->innertext,"<br/>\n";
   echo "Image source: ",$element->find('img',0)->src,"<br/>\n";
   echo "Link: ",$element->find('a',0)->href,"<br/>\n";
}
```

Produces this output:

```
Project name: KOSTIREV - THE REAL YOU 
Image source: https://ksr-ugc.imgix.net/projects/2123706/photo-original.png?v=1444253259&w=218&h=162&fit=crop&auto=format&q=92&s=9d6c437e96b720dce82fc9b598b3e8ae
Link: /projects/andrewkostirev/kostirev-the-real-you
```

Comment: tried this but i am getting this error
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @MArfan The ````find()```` function requires a second parameter, use 0 to grab the first element it finds. Example updated

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and it worked, thanks for the help! Here is something i made using primewire.ag as a example.... The goal here was to extract all the links of a given page.

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.primewire.ag/watch-2805774-Star-Wars-The-Last-Jedi-online-free');


// Find All Movie Links
$linkPrefix = 'http://primewire.ag';
$linkClass;
foreach($html->find(".movie_version_link") as $linkClass)  {
    echo "Link: ",$linkPrefix,$linkClass->find('a',0)->href,"<br/>\n";

}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is also a good library for scraping and traversing via HTML

https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser